# Blank page when trying to set up Apache and Django together

Tags: python, apache

I'm trying to set up Python and Django to work together with Apache.

The Django project gave me nothing but a blank page, so I've tried a sample I've found in many places:

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'This is my Website!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

I've added the following lines at the beginning of my app.py file:

```
#!C:/Program Files/Python34/python.exe
print('Content-Type: text/html')
print('\n\n')
```

I still get a blank page.

If I add the following code:

```
def testFunction(text):
    print(text)
testFunction('this works')
```

I get the appropriate output ('this works') so I guess my Python script *is* running. But how do I get the callable application(environ, start_response) to be called ?

I'm very new to Python/Django and somewhat new to Apache so I may be missing something trivial, but here's what I've tried:

- Looking into Apache log files, but there's nothing in error.log (even though I've set LogLevel to 'info')
- Making sure no other modules could interfere (no mod_php or mod_python are loaded)
- Adding WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
- Not using any VirtualHost or VirtualEnv to keep it simple
- Checking permissions on files and folders (all have read & execute checked)

Here is the section of my Apache config file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/PythonWorkspace/app.py"

<Directory "C:/PythonWorkspace">    
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py    
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Config is: Windows Server 2008 / Apache 2.4 w MOD_WSGI / Python 3.4 / Django 1.6.5

Thanks in advance for any pointers !

Comment: You mix different technology `CGI` and `WSGI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is used by `CGI`

```
print('Content-Type: text/html')
print('\n\n')

print('This is my Website!')
```

This is code is used by `WSGI`

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'This is my Website!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Apache is configured to use `CGI` for `.py` files

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

To use `WSGI` you need

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi # removed .py
AddHandler wsgi-script .py
```

Comment: I knew the answer would be simple, but this is beyond what I had expected! I somehow thought cgi was some kind of ancestor to wsgi and that it made sense.
Many thanks furas!

Comment: `CGI` is some kind of ancestor. `WSGI` was invented because `CGI` was too slow for some people. BTW: my yesterday's answer how to send image to browser with `WSGI`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24439673/1832058