# How Insert Python code in a Html File

Tags: python, html

How Insert Python code in a Html File  ?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>Hello Python!</h1>
<body>
 Here  i want to insert Python Code
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to display it or run it?

Comment: Are you coding this is Python? What problems are you having with inserting some code? I suspect I know what problems you are facing, but those are not unique to Python.

Comment: Create the complete file with Python or only the body and include it. ( like Virtual include in Apache)

Comment: I want a simple example for <TR> <TD>  and For...Loop of Python ?

Comment: You can't insert Python in HTML, you can only print HTML from Python. Python is not PHP.

Comment: See question and my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452343/blank-page-when-trying-to-set-up-apache-and-django-together

Comment: Where we can learn and get  flask or django framework for Python ?

Answer (score 1):

simple example for `CGI`

```
print('Content-Type: text/html')
print('\n\n')

print('''<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>Hello Python!</h1>
<body>''')

 # Here insert Python Code

print('''</body>
</html>''')
```

simple example for `WSGI`

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    output = '''<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <h1>Hello Python!</h1>
    <body>'''

    # Here insert Python Code which appends string to `output`

    output += '''</body>
    </html>'''

    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Comment: I have Installed Python in c:\Python34  Directory.
Installed EasyPhp for Apache and MySql

Now What Changes should i made in Apache config file to run my Python Files properly in Localhost  ?

Warm regards,
mk.

Comment: Apache needs `mod_wsgi` or `mod_cgi` to run Python, Perl or other script. Did you see  [previous link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452343/blank-page-when-trying-to-set-up-apache-and-django-together) ? There is Apache config example.

Comment: `CGI` seems to be easer to use but with `WSGI` you can use Python web frameworks like `Django` or mini web frameworks like `Flask`

Comment: Apache `WSGI` configuration in [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (or at least should not) mix python with HTML like you can do with PHP. For producing HTML dynamically, you can use any [templating library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org). You can also manipulate HTML as string directly in python script but that is obviously not recommended!

Comment: I have Installed Python in c:\Python34 Directory. Installed EasyPhp for Apache and MySql Now What Changes should i made in Apache config file to run my Python Files properly in Localhost ? Warm regards, mk

Comment: You can enable CGI for `.py` files. But why are you writing raw python for web? Why not a python web framework?

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to archive the same thing as with PHP and
`<php> smth </php>` tags. 
And it is impossible. You may try using something like [Brython](http://brython.info/doc/en/index.html).
This is only true options. Or just try Coffeescript which is pretty similar to Python and Ruby.
But if you need to do it on server side only, that mean the code will be executed on you side of wire and not on browser you can look at things like Flask. This framework is really simple and easy to use and how great templating engine.

PS. Including any code other than JS or language compiled to JS inside HTML is not a good idea. It is just asking for troubles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to design a website or web service with python language. You must use flask ot django ( my prefer is flask ) for this. Flask contains werkzeug and jinja2 packages for it. But you can't write something like javascript with python.